# Displaying A Laravel Collection in a blade template

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm having issues displaying a collection in a blade template.

```
$comments = Comment::all();

return view('comments/index')->with(compact('comments'));
```

The code for the blade is:

```
@isset($comments)

@foreach($comments as $comment)
    <div>
        <p>
            <a href="{{ url('comments/', $comment->id) }}"><{{ $comment->commentor }}</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <hr>
@endforeach
@endisset

@empty($comments)
    <div>
        <p>There were no comments available.</p>
        {{ $comments }}
    </div>
@endempty
```

But not sure how to get the data to render in the template.  It just renders a blankpage.

Comment: is there any error ?

Comment: If the whole page is blank, it sounds like a PHP error. Check your apache error.log

Comment: Also I think comments/index should be comments.index

Comment: No there is no error.  And the collection of comments is returned.  I did a dd() on it, and the Collection of comments came through, ok.  Its just on the blade template that it wont display.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead :

```
$comments = Comment::all();

return view('comments.index')->with(compact('comments'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use dot notation to reference the view folder structure, `view('comments.index')`. This represents the file `resources/views/comments/index.blade.php`. Use this.

```
@forelse ($comments as $comment)
    <div>
        <p>
            <a href="{{ url('comments/', $comment->id) }}">{{ $comment->commentor }}</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <hr/>
@empty
    <div>
        <p>There were no comments available.</p>
    </div>
@endforelse
```